# Moving to Unified API causes "AADSTS90092: Non-retryable error has occurred" in app-only authorisation

Tags: ms-office, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to move our existing app-only WAAD client application from requesting the 'Read directory data' permission on the 'Windows Azure Active Directory' application, to the 'Read directory data' permission on the 'Microsoft Graph' application.

The two things that have changed as a result of this migration are the 'requiredResourceAccess' section of the manifest, from:

```
{
  "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "resourceAccess": [
    {
      "id": "5778995a-e1bf-45b8-affa-663a9f3f4d04",
      "type": "Role"
    }
  ]
}
```

..to:

```
{
  "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "resourceAccess": [
    {
      "id": "7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61",
      "type": "Role"
    }
  ]
}
```

..and the authorisation Url, from:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F
```

..to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
```

The authorisation request shows the consent screen (as before, albeit with a slightly different description of the 'Read directory data' permission) but then on clicking 'Accept' is returned to the reply Url with an error:

```
http://dev.airhead.io/office365/integration?error=server_error&error_description=AADSTS90092%3a+Non-retryable+error+has+occurred.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+21679b2d-57ae-43b2-b991-a283f88082d7%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+7e21d08a-03d5-418e-81ea-0c9726563e65%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2016-01-25+16%3a06%3a43Z&state=xsrf%3dazc8Qch2zmyWy5ncXAgxnQ%26ctx%3d%26t%3d2016-01-25T16%3a06%3a36.2587332Z

AADSTS90092: Non-retryable error has occurred.
Trace ID: 21679b2d-57ae-43b2-b991-a283f88082d7
Correlation ID: 7e21d08a-03d5-418e-81ea-0c9726563e65
Timestamp: 2016-01-25 16:06:43Z
```

I've gone over the new documentation at https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/app_only, and I can't see any difference to what we do currently against `https://graph.windows.net/`.

Is there something else required to migrate over?